# How to store settings on jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Iam new in writing jquery plugins. I have code like this - only for ilustrate, real code have to store many variables.

```
<input type="button" name="firstbutton" />
<input type="button" name="secondbutton" />
```

and js:

```
$.fn.pluginname = function (options) {
    var opts = $.extend($.fn.pluginname.defaults, options);
    return this.each(function () {
       $.fn.pluginname.init($(this), opts);
    });
};
$.fn.pluginname.init = function (obj, opts) {
    this.sfobj = obj;
    this.sfopts = opts;
};
$.fn.pluginname.send = function () {
    //some logic to get right url, something like this
    var sendurl = this.sfopts.url;
};
```

and want to use:

```
//init first button
$("#firstbutton").pluginname({
  'url': "firsturl.com"
});
//init second button
$("#secondbutton").pluginname({
  'url': "secondurl.com"
});

//call when needed
$("#secondbutton").pluginname.send();
```

The problem is, when I init second button, init method rewrite sfopts variable. What is best practicies to store init settings of plugin? And is possible to call method like the last row of code and restore settings? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the best and easiest way to set defaults in a jQuery plugin is this:

```
var setting = $.extend({
    url: 'www.example.com',
    anotherSettingOption: 'another value'
}, options);
```

and when you need to call it you simply use:

`setting.url` or `setting.anotherSettingOption`

Comment: Thanks, but defaults are not problem. Problem is different settings of firstbutton and secondbutton and restore it when call some methods of plugin.